# прочесть ссылку из файла

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

я сделал парсер стихов с сайта. нужно из файла вытащить саму ссылку на страницу, откуда я парсил. (я просто указывал ссылку)
вот часть кода для чтения ссылки из файла и присваивания переменной url, с помощью который мы создаем запрос на эту страницу:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('ссылки на сайт.txt', 'r', encoding='utf=8')
a = f.read().split('\n')
url1 = a
```

в таком варианте программа не работает. но если в url просто указать ссылку на страницу, то все ок.

Comment: для начала, выведите в консоль url1

Comment: @splash58 вывел. появились 3 ссылки из файла.

Comment: видимо я понял, в чем проблема. ссылка из файла у меня выводится вот так: ['https://stihibase.ru/author/f/fet/mama_gljan_ka_iz_okoshka/', ''] и, соотвественно, запрос нельзя отправить по такой ссылке. как мне обрезать ненужные элементы, чтобы была чисто ссылка?

Comment: первый элемент из списка  `url1 = a[0]`

Comment: все получилось, спасибо!